# Question concerning the representation dimension of a special algebra

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

I would like to know, if the following problem is still open:

Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field of characteristic 3.

Determine the representation dimension of $k(C_3\times C_3)$, where $C_3$ denotes the cyclic group with 3 elements.

This is problem 2 of the following paper:

http://www2.iazd.uni-hannover.de/~tholm/ARTIKEL/BI_repdimkG_new.pdf

Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: As far as I know, this is still open.  However, I have not been following new results on representation dimension too closely.